# Form handling, using UNION, Division of 0 Error?

Tags: php, union

Stack, apologize for the wording of the title.
 *I am creating a search form that looks through my database,*

it takes an input ( **$searchquery** ), and an option in the  < select >,

I created a UNION so if they search in the option "whole site" it looks through both the blog && page database,

however, after doing so, I get 8 division of 0 errors ( on lines **27-30**)

I don't understand how I'm getting this, any advice would be greatly appreciated!!

```
<head>

    <title> Project # </title>
    <link href="../CSS/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

<?php
// force errors & warnings to show
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');

//search output variable
$search_output = "";



if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && !empty($_POST['searchquery'])){
    //filter the search query user Input
    $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);

    if($_POST['search_filter'] == 'Whole Site'){


////////////////////      \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\  //////////////
/// Getting the error on the three lines below, occured after adding UNION

        $sqlCmd = '("SELECT id, page_title AS title FROM pages WHERE page_title LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR page_body LIKE '%$searchquery%'") UNION
   ("SELECT id,blog_title AS title FROM blog WHERE blog_title LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR blog_body LIKE '%$searchquery%'")';

    } else if($_POST['search_filter'] == "Pages"){

        $sqlCmd = "SELECT id, page_title AS title FROM pages WHERE page_title LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR page_body LIKE '%$searchquery%'";

    } else if($_POST['search_filter'] == 'Blog'){

        $sqlCmd = "SELECT id,blog_title AS title FROM blog WHERE blog_title LIKE '%$searchquery%' OR blog_body LIKE '%$searchquery%'";

    }
    include_once('db_connect.php');

    $query = mysqli_query($link, $sqlCmd) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count > 1){
        $search_output .= "<hr /> $count results for $searchquery> ".$sqlCmd;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($link, $query)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $search_output .= "Item ID: $id - $title <br /> ";

        }

    } else {

        $search_output = " <hr /> 0 results for $searchquery ".$sqlCmd;
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="search.php">


    <label for="searchquery">Search</label>
    <input type="text" name="searchquery">
    <input type="submit" value="submit"><br />
    <br />
    <label for="search_filter">Where Would you like to look?</label>
    <select name="search_filter">
        <option value="Whole Site"> Whole Site</option>
        <option value="Pages"> Pages</option>
        <option value="Blog"> Blogs</option>

    </select>
</form>

<div>
    <?php  echo $search_output ;?>
</div>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error on your syntax. You did not escaped the single quotes correctly.

```
<?php

$sqlCmd = '("SELECT id, page_title AS title FROM pages WHERE page_title LIKE \'%$searchquery%\' OR page_body LIKE \'%$searchquery%\'") UNION ("SELECT id,blog_title AS title FROM blog WHERE blog_title LIKE \'%$searchquery%\' OR blog_body LIKE \'%$searchquery%\'")';
```

Also, be sure to escape those values to prevent sql injections :)

Comment: Awesome yeah, a friend had pointed this out to me and I forgot to come back with an answer. But this was the problem